# Interpretation of time series ACF function

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

What can be told about a time series using this ACF plot?

I think it isn't stationary. Do you see here something else?

[image]

Comment: what is the frequency of measurement   ? why don't you post the data and I will torture it with my toys

Comment: you have about 100 observations .